# IoT Early Flood Detection with the ability to connect to IoT azure HUB

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, dynamics-365, azure-iot-central

Not sure you're the right audience but I'll try my luck. Trying to check where I can purchase a simple IoT device that can be connected to IoT azure HUB and later also Connected Field Service (Dynamics 365 field service) for  demonstration and POC.

I was thinking of something as simple as a flood controller? Anyone have an idea where I can get such a device?

Comment: Please have a look at these docs https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/town-of-cary-innovates-flood-prediction-with-iot/ , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/field-service/developer/connected-field-service-architecture and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/field-service/connected-field-service see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [AshokPeddakotla-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188729/ashokpeddakotla-msft) posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

Using Water level Sensors, we might be able to predict the floods.
Below are highlights of how the solution can be built .

- [Microsoft Azure IoT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/)  enabled a highly secure and reliable communication to ingest stormwater levels over an Firstnet LTE wireless connection. The team used Azure IoT Hub to provision, authenticate, and manage the two-way communication to the sensors.
- [SAS Analytics for IoT](https://www.sas.com/en_us/software/analytics-iot.html)  combined streaming sensors or gauges and weather data for real-time scoring, dashboarding, and historical reporting.
- [SAS Visual Analytics](https://www.sas.com/en_us/software/visual-analytics.html)  provided interactive dashboard, reports, business intelligence, and analytics. The dashboard is integrated with ESRI ArcGIS for additional geographic analysis and data visualization.
- [Microsoft Azure Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/)  seamlessly integrated with Salesforce and other third-party applications.
- [Microsoft Azure Synapse Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/synapse-analytics/)  provides data warehousing for Big Data analytics.

Complete solution is available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/town-of-cary-innovates-flood-prediction-with-iot/)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/field-service/developer/connected-field-service-architecture, https://www.floodsafety.com/national/life/statistics.htm#biblio